# HTML5 canvas drawimage avoid first time load latency

Tags: html, html5-canvas, drawimage

I am working on a sidescroller game and it has tiles that I am loading in as needed a little ahead of the player. They are 1000x1000px so not insignificant loading times.

While loading in the first time drawimage is called there is a noticeable latency of what I think is it transferring to the gpu.

I can preload everything to avoid this but would rather not.
I have tried onload then decode to have the image ready but I think that just decodes it on the cpu and the latency of transferring to the gpu is still present.

I could be wrong entirely about if this is the case its just what I am leaning towards.

Any ideas on how I can get it to the gpu canvas asynchronously?

Comment: In the performance console I found the frames on the initial display (even with createImageBitmap) it shows
    
    System (self) 54ms
    System (children) 0ms
    Scripting 2ms
    Rendering 0ms
    Painting 0ms
    54ms total
The scripting lines up with what I measure 2ms

Answer (score 1):

[`createImageBitmap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap) is made just for this: it will create an `ImageBitmap` object, that does live in the GPU*, readily available for fast rendering.
If you pass this method a `Blob` holding the data of a bitmap image, it will even take care of all the reading and decoding in an optimized way.

`HTMLImageElement#decode()` may indeed resolve before the image buffer has been moved to the GPU, so for best performances, you're better using an `ImageBitmap`*.

<sup>*That is how it's supposed to work, and how it does work in Chrome and Safari. Firefox still has a *fake* `ImageBitmap` implementation which holds the data only on the CPU side... On that browser, using an `ImageBitmap` is not necessarily better, yet.</sup>

Comment: I implemented createImageBitmap and it looks a little better (could be my imagination) but its still not smooth. Its hard to diagnose since the time in my javascript draw function doesnt ever exceed 2ms so I cant pinpoint whats going on. Maybe I can measure the time in between frames so see actual draw times. I am still leaning towards its not on the gpu when it goes to draw the first time.

Comment: I disabled 2d canvas hardware acceleration and its slower obviously but it has the same stutter when a new tile is drawn the first time. I am really at a loss now

Comment: That's really weird. You have the same behavior on multiple browsers? Can you test on a different device? Could you share a small test case where you still see the issue?

Comment: Yes same issue on chrome and firefox on 2 computers

Comment: I thought of something. The image loaded is 1000x1000 but its rendered at less resolution so what im theorizing is createImageBitmap is working on the regular image but when I drawimage it has to scale it. I would figure that would be done on the GPU but I cant tell what happens behind the scenes. I am going to try rendering at 1000x1000 to see if this leads anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Loading images while the game is running is likely going to be slower than loading them all at once first. One of the fastest ways to do it is to have all images and animations on one single sprite sheet, the loading of that one sprite sheet then dictates when the game is ready to run, and you blit from that sprite sheet onto a canvas or canvases. That is, you drawImage from a section of the sprite sheet Image onto a section of the canvas, to scroll you change where you draw from and to.

Comment: Each tile is 1000x1000px, that would make a HUGE spritesheet, which would certainly not fit in most GPU memory and thus would be as slow as having separated files.

Comment: Theres 4 tiles on screen at a time so its 4000px wide by 1000px high thats not a lot in my book and my dev computer has a 3090 with 24gb of gpu memory so plenty to fit. 4000x1000x3=12000000 thats 12mb I dont think theres many gpus that cant handle that these days. If I can get this solved I can optimize for lesser computers but I dont think gpu memory capacity wise is the problem.